# Are MySQL triggers subject to user limitations?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am currently constructing a database, and I occasionally make use of triggers for various functions such as audit tables.

Recently I realized that I could simplify a repetitive process that I was previously doing with `PHP` with a trigger.  However, it requires use of `DELETE`. I typically try to limit users abilities to basic commands such as `INSERT`.

That said, I am curious if triggers are subject to user limitations. For example, can a trigger make use of `DELETE` even if the user is restricted to executing an explicit query with that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making SQL queries to a database from a PHP script there are no limitations. Anything the root/admin of your database can do from MySQL directly can be triggered from a PHP script.

This is because in order to establish a connection to that database from a PHP script you need secure login information. Hopefully only the root/admin user would have access to the main account information of this database. This assumed security precaution is why these remote triggers from PHP are treated as commands from a root user and have no restrictions.

Comment: It could be that I misunderstand the concept, but I am under the impression that I could limit user control to my database via my PHP scripts. Currently, I am using PHP's PDO. The login credentials linked to those scripts correspond to a SQL server account that I have limited to what I believe is necessary. In this case, the ability to insert values and pull row values - nothing such as delete rows or drop entire tables.  And I don't mean executing triggers from PHP; I mean associating a SQL trigger to a specific table.

Comment: Oh alright; yes if you choose to connect with a restricted user then yes that is true. Usually people just connect with the root user because usually whoever is writing the PHP can be trusted to maintain database integrity. But yes, users can only be granted  access to execute triggers in which they have permission enabled; so you should be able to restrict some users access to those triggers if you wish.